# Dockerで起動後にすぐ終了してしまうコンテナに対してコマンドを実行したい

Tags: docker, redmine

`docker start` 後にすぐ終了してしまうコンテナに対して、特定のファイルを削除するコマンドを実行したいです。

https://hub.docker.com/_/redmine/
こちらのDockerイメージを使ってRedmineを動かしていたのですが、PC再起動後に再び `docker start` したらすぐに終了してしまうようになりました。
どうも、 `/usr/src/redmine/tmp/pids/server.pid` が居残ってるのが問題みたいなので削除しようと思うのですが、その方法が分かりません。

何かいい方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: すぐ終了とはどのくらいの時間でしょうか？ 試したこと無いのですが `ducker export` した tar  に pid が含まれていれば、展開してpid削除後、tarに固めて `docker import` すればどうかと思いますが、`export` は実行できますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！
終了はだいたい開始してから1秒程度です。その間に `docker exec` で対象ファイルを消そうとしましたが起動していないと言われてしまいました。
`docker export` を行ってみましたら、中にpidファイルがありましたので、それを削除してまたtarに固めて `docker import` したのですが、 `docker run` 実行時に `Error response from daemon: No command specified` と言われ、 `rails server -b 0.0.0.0` を指定したらパスが通ってないと言われたりしてしまいました。
でも、 `import` まわりをもっと調べたり、tarからデータだけ引っこ抜いて新しいコンテナでやり直せば出来そうですので、その辺りを見てみようと思います。

Comment: 取り急ぎ、 `export` したファイルを新しいコンテナに入れる形で復旧致しました。情報ありがとうございます。

Comment: 解決につながったようでよかったです。もしよろしければ、追記した部分を回答に書いたうえで解決マークをつけてください。今後、有効な対策があると分かれば 今後検索してきた人への手助けになります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

標題とは異なる対応ですが、問題が解決しましたので記載致します。

データを引っ張りだして、新しいコンテナに入れる形で復旧致しました。

1. `docker export` を使用して対象コンテナをエクスポート
2. エクスポートしたtarを展開して、redmineの必要なデータを取り出す
3. 新しいredmineコンテナを作成
4. また同じ過ちを繰り返さないように、 `/docker-entrypoint.sh` に `rm -f /usr/src/redmine/tmp/pids/server.pid` を追記
5. 取り出したファイルを新しいコンテナにコピーする
6. コピーしたファイルの所有者を `redmine:redmine` に変更
7. コンテナを再起動

また、私がコピーしたファイルは以下です

- /usr/src/redmine/sqlite/redmine.db
- /usr/src/redmine/files/* (空でしたが...)
- /usr/src/redmine/config/configuration.yml
- /usr/src/redmine/public/themes/使っていたテーマ